# pandas dataframe prevent inserting duplicate records

Tags: pandas, dataframe, insert, duplicates

I'm trying to accomplish something quite plain indeed, but my previous searches were unsuccessful.
I have an existing dataframe generated from a multi-sheet spreadsheet.
From each sheet I loaded a number of records, every sheet corresponds to a 'Match' column in the df.
Now i need to insert multiple records OUTSIDE of the spreadsheet, so it's easy to prepare a dict like this :

```
    for m  in range(from_match, to_match):
        d = {'Minuto': 0, 'Azione': event, 'Giocatore': player, 'Match': m, 'Extra': 1}
```

The 'Extra' field indicates that these records are NOT loaded from the spreadsheet.
The problem is that a `df.append(d, ignore_index=True)`,  always insert the record no matter if it already exists.
That is not the expected result.
The ideal (for me) solution, would be something like this :

```
    for m  in range(from_match, to_match):
        d = {'Minuto': 0, 'Azione': event, 'Giocatore': player, 'Match': m, 'Extra': 1}
        # insert some check here 
        if record d do not exists:
           df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

I've played with `df.isin`, I've seen solution based on merging dataframes, but it seems to me that something like this shouldn'be complicated at all.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at pandas `.drop_duplicates(subset=, keep=)` append all the data and just filter out the duplicates post.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.
Yeah, but drop_duplicates is just an 'accessory after the fact'.
Not exactly the method i was looking for...